# Check Machine Identity programmatically with ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a MVC3 application that will be hosted on IIS7 with a SQL Server repository.

I need to limit certain actions on the site to a single machine and I am trying to figure out the best way to implement this.

I am using forms based membership with roles for login accounts but because of our client they don't want the "sign in" machine to require a special login account so I need another way to confirm that you are on the correct machine to perform "sign in" activities. If a staff member is at home and logs into the site we don't want them accessing certains function from anywhere but the one designated computer.

We also need the capability of letting an admin easily change the "sign in" computer in case of equipment failure.

Comment: OP is looking for code to solve a specific problem.  Belongs on SO.

Comment: Yet stack overflow wants code posted with question. I was fishing for ideas.

Comment: Just be careful to avoid open discussions.  Neither site allows them.  Consider adding more requirements.  E.G.  I have little network control.

Comment: Network control is not a problem :). Seems like you are being picky just to be picky.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Not sure why you edited out my "thanks in advance" where I'm from being polite is generally not frowned upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Machine name, or IP address is really not a horridly secure way to do this -- really easy to spoof. You really should be authenticating against an external source, not checking if an easily changable with the right tools magic machine name is the same.

What you might want to look at here is client certificates -- AFAIK, they can be installed on a machine (rather than user) level, there is lots of baked in support and you aren't rolling your own security scheme.

Comment: External source? What would you suggest?

Comment: I didn't have a great specific idea -- not really sure what is on the table and how secure it needs to be. But there is alot that can go wrong with arbitrary measurements (machinename or IP), MAC address is perhaps better but can also easily be spoofed.

Comment: Yeah. Part of the problem is my client does not understand the need for any security at all but I dont want him to get caught with his pants down if you know what I mean.

Comment: Ah. Well, you could go as simple as using an API key combined with the IP adderess then verify it on another machine, such as the database server. In any case, I'd make it easy to remove -- as soon as the CEO finds out he can't change the payroll from his beach cabana he'll make you pull it :)

Comment: Thanks I will look into certificates.

Answer (score 1):

Can you fix the IP address of the 'sign in' computer?  It's not fool-proof but it's easy to determine from a browser session and coupled with user authentication it should provide reasonable protection.

If your clients are really paranoid you could attempt to query back the MAC address of the fixed IP address as well, and make sure it matches what you expect for the 'sign in' computer.

Comment: I think we can give the machine a fixed IP I would need to check with their IT department. My concern is implementation in code.

Comment: Scratch that got the code figured out :). Now to check with IT.